# FitText.js makes text bigger rather than smaller

Tags: jquery-plugins, font-size, fittextjs

I'm using the FixText jquery plugin. It's supposed to scale down text so a headline fits the available width without wrapping onto 2 lines. http://fittextjs.com/

On my site the plug in is resizing the text, however its making it larger when it should make it smaller!

http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/text-fit/

The code that initializes it is in `script.js` and the line is `jQuery('.view-display-id-page  p').fitText();`

The instructions say that the element must be display block and have a width (but this can be a `%`) with CSS, which I've done. I have no idea where to begin with this issue! Thanks.

Comment: It works for me (chrome 29). Perhaps its a problem with your browser; which are you using?

Comment: In Firefox 23/Linux I see the same issue as the OP says.

Answer (score 3):

Firebug console gives this:

```
TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
```

meaning that jQuery `on()` is not an available function. [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was added in version 1.7, but in your source you use jQuery v1.4.4. If you are allowed to, try an upgrade to a newer version >= 1.7 and see if this solves the issue. The error is generated by a call to `on()` in [jquery.fittext.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js/blob/2d3574e549ec0f4074be2abf45aecfdd367ab3f9/jquery.fittext.js#L37).

If you can't update jQuery, maybe you can change `jquery.fittext.js` to use other way to attach event handlers to elements instead of on(), like `bind()`.

**--UPDATE**

You could also try to tweak up/down the [compressor setting](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js#the-compressor) of FitText.js. Setting its value to `3.0` fixed the issue for me locally, please experiment. Now `scripts.js` looks like:

```
... other js code ...

//jQuery('.view-display-id-page  p').fitText();
jQuery('.view-display-id-page  p').fitText(3.0);

... other js code ...
```

The font size also resizes when resizing the browser window. Finer tuning should be possible via [minFontSize & maxFontSize](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js#minfontsize--maxfontsize) settings, too.

Comment: I see you applied `width: 100%` to the outer div. Not sure it will, but can you try to add the CSS rule (or `width: auto`) to <p>I believe education is...</p> and see if it works?

Comment: Ive changed it locally but it doesn't have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

it's very unstable with multiline.
You should use this one: https://github.com/STRML/textFit